# Create graphs inside table using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx, tikz-arrows

I would like to create the same word table using latex.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tabularx}


% New Commands
\newcommand{\sdgarr}[2]{
    \tikz \draw[-{Straight Barb[line width=.2cm,line join=round,line cap=round]},line width=.2cm,color=#2,line cap=round,rotate=#1-45] (0,0) - - (1,1);
}
\newcommand{\sdgcir}[1]{
    \tikz \draw[fill=#1,color=#1] (0,0) circle (5pt);
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.95\linewidth}{|X|X|}
    \centering
\hline
1 NO \newline POVERTY \newline
\sdgarr{red}{45}
& 
2 ZERO  \newline Hunger \newline
\sdgcir{gray}
\\

\hline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please see the answer below-- I have changed newline to thead using the  makecell package -- the font of number 1 is increased -- tha arrow needs to be rotated -- I think you will be able to work it out now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**
Considered are my suggestion from the my answer an the your next [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575137/create-graphs-inside-table-using-tikz-with-many-rows-and-columns)

You may liked the following solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass[table]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}


% arrows
\newcommand{\rotarr}[2]{\centerline{
\tikz[baseline]{%
    \path[draw=#1,line width=3mm, line join=round,line cap=round,
         -{Straight Barb[scale=2, line join=round,line cap=round]},
         rotate around={#2:(0,0)}]  (-0.4\linewidth,0) -- (0.4\linewidth,0);}
               }}
% circle fill, meaning zero?
\newcommand{\zero}{\centerline{
\tikz[baseline]{\node[circle, fill=gray, minimum size=0.8\linewidth] {};}
                  }}
% columns headers
\newcommand{\cellhead}[2]{\smallskip
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} >{\sffamily\bfseries}l @{\,}
                           >{\sffamily\bfseries}l
                       @{} }
    \multirow[b]{2}{*}{\scalebox{2.8}{#1}} &   {\makecell[lt]{#2}}
    \end{tabular}   }  


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{cyan}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
    \hline
\cellhead{1}{NO\\ POVERTY}
\uparr{red}
    &   \cellhead{2}{ZERO\\ HUNGER}
        \zero
        &   \cellhead{3}{WHAT\\ EVER}
            \downarr{blue} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

As you can notice, in above solution are defined three commands (from scratch) which simplify formation your table cells. Command for arrows enable to define their colors separately.

Comment: my table is 3 row by six columns
```
\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
 \cellhead{7}{AFFORDABLE AND}{CLEAN ENERGY} \uparr{red}
 & \cellhead{8}{DECENT WORD AND}{ECONOMIC GROWTH} \zero
 &   \cellhead{9}{INDUSTRY, INNOVATION}{AND INFRASTRUCTURE} \downarr{blue}
 & \cellhead{10}{REDUCED}{INEQUALITIES} \zero
 & 
 % &   \cellhead{11}{SUSTAINABLE CITIES}{AND COMMUNITIES} \downarr{blue}
 & \cellhead{12}{RESPONSIBLE}{CONSUMPTION}{AND PRODUCTION} \zero \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: 1. why the table is not sizable?
2. what if one of the cell is three lines and the number should be starched to rows only?
3. If i have different arrows (different direction), do i have to create other commands, or should create command arrow, then use IF inside of the function?
4. \uparr function, can accept color in hex format or RGB?

Comment: @Mohamed, if your real table has more columns and rows, than showed cells can serve as building boxes to determine other cells. Anwy, if you like to clarify something in your question, please edit it and add new information, however, answer provide one of possible solution for your problem.

Comment: @Mohamed, sorry, I do not understood your second comment. If you have new problems not mentioned in your question, please ask new question. As is question now, answer solve showed reported problem.

Comment: I am sorry if i gave you hard time. I did not know that you solve this way.  I edited the arrow to accept degree (rotation)
```
% New Commands
\newcommand{\arr}[2]{
\hfil\tikz{\path[draw=#1,line width=3mm, line join=round,line cap=round,
                 -{Straight Barb[scale=1.5, line join=round,line cap=round]},
                 rotate=#2-45
                 ]  (0,0) -- (1.6,1.6);}}
```

Comment: my second comment: 
in case of this
```
\cellhead{12}{RESPONSIBLE}{CONSUMPTION}{AND PRODUCTION} \zero \\
 \hline
```
How I edit the command to accept third argument: 
```
\newcommand{\cellhead}[3]{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*{2}{>{\sffamily\bfseries}l@{\,}}}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\scalebox{2.8}{#1}} &   #2\\[-3pt]
                                        &   #3
    \end{tabular}\par\smallskip       }
```

Comment: @Mohamed, if you not liked my answer, than not consider it. You still have another answer, it my be more appropriate to you. Ask author for further help. For new demands, let me repeat again, ask new question. For me this is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117301/discussion-between-mohamed-and-zarko).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}

% New Commands
\newcommand{\sdgarr}{
    \tikz \draw[-{Straight Barb[line width=.2cm,line join=round,line cap=round]},line width=.2cm,color=red,line cap=round] (0,0) - - (1,1);
}
\newcommand{\sdgcir}[1]{
    \tikz \draw[fill=#1,color=#1] (0,0) circle (15pt);
}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bl}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|L{1in}|p{1in}|}
%    \centering
{\bfseries\Huge 1} \thead{NO \\ POVERTY }
\centering\sdgarr
& 
\thead{2 ZERO  \\ Hunger \\
\sdgcir{gray}}\\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```