# Create graphs inside table using tikz with many rows and columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx, tikz-arrows

I want to replicate the table (3 by 6), and it should be sizable in order to get inside mini page.

```
documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{tabularx}


% New Commands
\newcommand{\sdgarr}[2]{
    \tikz \draw[-{Straight Barb[line width=.2cm,line join=round,line cap=round]},line width=.2cm,color=#2,line cap=round,rotate=#1-45] (0,0) - - (1,1);
}
\newcommand{\sdgcir}[1]{
    \tikz \draw[fill=#1,color=#1] (0,0) circle (5pt);
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{0.95\linewidth}{|X|X|}
    \centering
\hline
1 NO \newline POVERTY \newline
\sdgarr{red}{45}
& 
2 ZERO  \newline Hunger \newline
\sdgcir{gray}
\\

\hline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

I asked similar question, but I was not clear enough.

[Create graphs inside table using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575082/create-graphs-inside-table-using-tikz)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

As promised I wee bit improve suggest solution:

- new commands definitions
- align of images
- I still left to write correct text in table as well select desired images in cells to OP (this now should not be big deal)

[image]

```
\documentclass[table]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% arrows
\newcommand{\rotarr}[2]{\centerline{
\tikz[baseline]{%
    \path[draw=#1,line width=3mm, line join=round,line cap=round,
         -{Straight Barb[scale=1.2, line join=round,line cap=round]},
         rotate around={#2:(0,0)}]  (-0.4\linewidth,0) -- (0.4\linewidth,0);}
               }}
% circle fill, meaning zero?
\newcommand{\zero}{\centerline{
\tikz[baseline]{\node[circle, fill=gray, minimum size=0.8\linewidth] {};}
                  }}
% columns headers                  
\newcommand{\cellhead}[2]{\smallskip\centerline{
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} >{\sffamily\bfseries}l @{\,}
                           >{\sffamily\bfseries}l
                       @{} }
    \multirow[b]{2}{*}{\scalebox{2.8}{#1}} &   {\makecell[lt]{#2}}
    \end{tabular}   }  }

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{cyan}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{6}{X|}}
% first two-line row
   \hline
\cellhead{1}{NO\\POVERTY}
    &   \cellhead{2}{ZERO\\HUNGER}
        &   \cellhead{3}{WHAT\\EVER}
            &   \cellhead{4}{NO\\POVERTY}
                &   \cellhead{5}{ZERO\\HUNGER}\
                    &   \cellhead{6}{WHAT\\EVER\\NEWER}  \\
\rotarr{red}{45}
    &   \zero
        &   \rotarr{purple}{-90}
            &   \rotarr{orange}{0}
                &   \rotarr{teal}{90}
                    &   \rotarr{orange}{0}              \\
% second two-line row
    \hline
\cellhead{7}{NO\\POVERTY}
    &   \cellhead{8}{ZERO\\HUNGER}
        &   \cellhead{9}{WHAT\\EVER}
            &   \cellhead{10}{NO\\POVERTY}
                &   \cellhead{11}{ZERO\\HUNGER}\
                    &   \cellhead{12}{WHAT\\EVER\\NEWER}  \\
\rotarr{red}{45}
    &   \zero
        &   \rotarr{purple}{-90}
            &   \rotarr{orange}{0}
                &   \rotarr{teal}{90}
                    &   \rotarr{orange}{0}              \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

- it is not clear, what you mean with "sizable":

  - the font size used in the table must be set manually so that the text doesn't protrude from the cells
  - size of images are now determined by cell width, consequently their sizes will always adopted to cells' widths
- that images are aligned as desired, they are now set in separate row. So far that was only way that I was able to achieve this.

Comment: if we use this 
\cellhead{6}{RESPONSIBLE}{\makecell[lt]{CONSUMPTION\\AND PRODUCTION}}
the table is not sizable and arrows/circle are not bottomed aligned? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Mohamed, see edited answer. Now the code is considerably improved.

Comment: I am wondering why \cellhead command is not based on tabularx instead of tabular.
try to use \cellhead{6}{RESPONSIBLE\\CONSUMPTION\\AND PRODUCTION}  \\, and you will understand my point....

Comment: I am not good at latex since I start using it recently. If I can solve, I would not have asked for a help at all. Any way. Thanks for your great help.